Is my understanding of the definition of a metric space correct?
The definition of metric space that I am using is as follows:

Let $X$ be a nonempty set. A function $d:X\times X\to \Bbb R$ is said to be a metric or a distance function on $X$ if $d$ satisfies the following properties:
(i) $d(x, y)\geq 0$ for all $x, y\in X$ and $d(x,y) = 0$ iff $x = y.$
(ii) $d(x , y) = d(y , x)$ for all $x,y\in X.$
(iii) $d(x, z) \leq d(x, y) + d(y, z)$ for all $x, y, z \in X.$ This is known as the triangle inequality.

I had a little confusion regarding aciom (iii) in the definition above.
When they say, $\forall x,y,z\in X$ the inequality $d(x, z) \leq d(x, y) + d(y, z)$ holds true, since there is no restriction on $x,y,z$ so I can assume that they are any arbitrary element in $X.$ Can't we alternatively say that $d(x, z) + d(x, y) \geq d(y, z)$ by interchanging these symbols $x,y,z$ with each other or maybe from symmetry? Similarly, I feel we may also say that $d(x, z)+ d(y, z) \geq d(x, y)$ due to the same reason.
For that matter, I interpret the axiom (iii) as follows:
(iii)(M) For all $x, y, z \in X$ either all or one of the inequalities: $d(x, z) \leq d(x, y) + d(y, z),\space d(x, z) + d(x, y) \geq d(y, z),\space d(x, z)+ d(y, z) \geq d(x, y)$ holds true.
So for questions that asks to show that a non empty set $X$ with a given function $d$ (,defined on $X\times X$) is a metric space, we may show that the axioms (i),(ii) and (iii)(M) holds true. What this means is that if we're able to show that axioms (i) and (ii) holds true, and if for some arbitrary $x,y,z\in X$ we are able to prove any one of the inequalities: $d(x, z) \leq d(x, y) + d(y, z),\space d(x, z) + d(x, y) \geq d(y, z),\space d(x, z)+ d(y, z) \geq d(x, y)$ to be true then we can say that $(X,d)$ is a metric space. In other words, I am simply deleting axiom (iii) in the definition of a metric space and replacing it with (iii)(M) instead.
I want to know whether my interpretations and understanding of this is correct or not? I have just started learning about metric spaces which is precisely why this confusion arose. If my interpretations are not justified, please be kind enough to correct me.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

It is relatively simple to show that axiom (iii)(M) is a corrolary of the standard axioms, if axioms (i), (ii) and (iii) hold, then (iii)(M) also holds.
However, what you are asking is if you can replace (iii) with (iii)(M). In order to do that, you have to show that (iii) also follows from (i), (ii) and (iii)(M), which you did not yet do.

In fact, you cannot prove that your modified set of axioms is equivalent, because there exists a counterexample. Let $X=\{a,b,c\}$ and $d$ be defined as
$$\begin{align}d(a,a)=d(b,b)=d(c,c)=0\\
d(a,b)=d(b,a)=1\\
d(a,c)=d(c,a)=1\\
d(b,c)=d(c,b)=3\end{align}$$
then, axioms (i) and (i) hold by definition, and axiom (iii)(M) also holds:
Let $x,y,z$ be arbitrary values of $X$. Now there are two options:

If any two of them are equal, then WLOG we can say $x=y$, in which case then $d(x, z)=d(y,z)=d(y, z)+0=d(y,z)+d(x,y)$ which means that one inequality of (iii)(M) is satisfied.
If the three are different, then WLOG  we can say $x=a, y=b, z=c$, in which case the inequality $d(x, y) \leq d(x,z)+d(y,z)$ translates to $1\leq 3+1$ which is true. So, one of the inequalities you required in axiom (iii)(M) holds, which means (iii)(M) is also satisfied.

However, the set $(X,d)$ as defined above is not true, because the standard axiom (iii) does not hold. To see that, you can set $x=a, y=b, z=c$ and notice that $d(x,z)=3$ while $d(x,y)+d(y,z)=2$.

+1) I wrongly started with $\forall x,y,z[\cdots]\vee\forall x,y,z[\cdots]\vee\forall x,y,z[\cdots]$ instead of $\forall x,y,z[\cdots\vee\cdots\vee\cdots]$

@5xum Can you please explain why is (iii) equivalent to the statement: "For all $x, y, z \in X$ all the inequalities: $$d(x, z) \leq d(x, y) + d(y, z),\space d(x, z) + d(x, y) \geq d(y, z),\space d(x, z)+ d(y, z) \geq d(x, y)$$ hold true." ?

@ThomasFinley That's more-or-less what "for all" means.  $x, y, z$ are all in $X$, therefore axiom (iii) says $d(x,z)<d(x,y)+d(y,z)$; $x, z, y$ are also all in $X$, therefore axiom (iii) says $d(x,y) < d(x,z)+d(z,y)$; $y, x, z$ are also also all in $X$, therefore axiom (iii) says $d(y,z) < d(y,x)+d(x,z)$. For all means not only that you can pick any three points, but (if the expression isn't completely symmetric) in any order. (And I suppose even if the expression is completely symmetric.)

@ThomasFinley Because given (ii), statement (iii) can be proven from it, and it can be proven from (iii). This is true in general: Whenever you have a statement $P(x,y)$, the statements "$\forall x,y: P(x,y)$" and $\forall x,y: (P(x,y)\land (P(y,x))$" are equivalent.

For any three points $x,y,z$ in metric space $X$, it is true that $d(x,y) \leq d(x,z) + d(y,z)$, so, that is simply what you need to show if $X$ is indeed a metric space (given symmetry and zero property- the other two axioms- are satisfied). Of course you can interchange these points, the axiom allows for that from the condition "$\forall x,y,z$", but when you generally are working on proving if some space is a metric space, for eg: $\mathbb{R}^n$, you don't do it triplet by triplet. You just start with three arbitrary points. (Unless your space is finite or something specific).
The extra assertion: "either one or all of the inequalities hold" is not required, because that all of them hold is a consequence of one of them holding, making it redundant.

Can you explain the reason behind the assertion in your last paragraph? What I meant was deleting axiom (iii) and replacing it with (iii)(M) instead.
